# Error after deploying JRuby WAR file using apache tomcat?? why?

Tags: java, tomcat, jruby, warbler

[We have created WAR file in JRuby and deployed on Apache tomcat, But when i run Apache tomcat, i saw above image as a error messaage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9uV9.png)

I am getting errors :

Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.10
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.3.pre1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.3.pre1
Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2
You did not specify how you would like Rails to report deprecation notices for your development environment, please set config.active_support.deprecation to :log at config/environments/development.rb
/home/bvc-10/tomcat/webapps/sk/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:102 warning: already initialized constant PDF

Answer (score 0):

those seem to be warnings that you should be able to safely ignore if you unset your env variables to point to any gem home location (`unset GEM_HOME`, `unset GEM_PATH`)